# Remove empty childrens from the array in angular

Tags: angular

JSON
0
title : "System Setting"
id : "System Setting"
children
0
1
children
0
2
children
0
1
title : "Menu Master1"
2
title : "MenuMaster 2"
3
title : "MenuMaster 3"
title : "Setting"

Expected result-
JSON
0
title : "System Setting"
id : "System Setting"

children
0
1
title : "Menu Master1"
2
title : "MenuMaster 2"
3
title : "MenuMaster 3"
title : "Setting"

Comment: Please elaborate your question and describe your problem a little bit more. Because from your question I can not understand your expectation.

Comment: I want to remove the empty children from my array.I want result like this-                                                                                  
    {
    id: 'system_setting',
    title: 'System Setting',
    children: [
      {
        id: 'setting',
        title: 'Setting',
        children: [
          {
            id: 'Menu Master',
            title: 'Menusss Master',
          },

Comment: OK, fine. I understand that this is your final results. However, give at least the JSON object or array from which you want to derive these results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this, => logs result in console as of now

```
function removeEmpties() {
    var data = [
      {
         title: "System Setting",
         id: "System Setting",
         children: [
           {
           },
           {
             title : "Menu Master1"
           }
         ]
      },
      {}
    ];

    var result = [];
    data.map(function(f) {
        if (f && f.hasOwnProperty('title')) { // add constraint
            if (f && f.children && f.children.length > 0) // add constraint
            {
                 f.children = f.children.filter(function(c) { // add constraint
                    return c && c.hasOwnProperty('title');
                 });
            }
            result.push(f);
        }
    });
    console.log(result); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteEmptyChildren(node) {
    // assumes node is not empty
    if (Array.isArray(node.children)) {
        node.children = node.children.filter(
            function(child) {
                if (isEmpty(child)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    deleteEmptyChildren(child);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your response, but it's not working for me.

Comment: can you share JSON array structure?

Comment: [{"title":"System Setting","id":"System Setting","children":[{},{"children":[{}]},{"children":[{},{"title":"Menu Master1"},{"title":"MenuMaster 2"},{"title":"MenuMaster 3"}],"title":"Setting"}]}]